# Use of the plural of tang (as in taste or smell)

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

Discussing with friends, we decided tang (like a flavour or smell) is a noun. Smell, when pluralised is smells. Flavour - flavours.  What's the plural of tang?

We believe it would be simply 'tangs' but it sounds crazily weird in a sentence. Eg if you mix chilli and blue cheese together,  would it be possible to say 'the meal had two strong tangs'?

Comment: It's possible, but it is crazily weird; like saying *two strong smells* or *two strong tastes*. We tend to use these words as uncountable, even if it's possible to pluralize. On the other hand, *flavor* is often used as countable (*two strong flavors* sounds perfectly fine).

Comment: What @Daniel said. Pluralising ***tang*** is like saying *"The spaghetti and linguine had good **bites**"* (they were both cooked "al dente"). Not very likely.

Comment: You don't need to pluralize as far as I can see: 'I like them all for **their tang.** ' And 'their two strong variations of tang' -- still in singular.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with this sentence:

> When I tasted the "special elixir" that the children were selling in front of their house, I immediately recognized the unmistakable tangs of Tang and Strawberry Kool-Aid.

Though tangs tend to come individually, rather than in combination, they don't have to.